# Sort "Date" in Multi-Index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Given this multi-index dataframe,

```
Units                               Import                                               Export
Date     01012019  01022019  02012019  02022019   03012019  03022019   01012019  01022019  02012019  02022019   03012019  03022019
Period
   0        4          3         1         1         2          4          2         2         1         1          2         2  
   1        2          2         3         2         4          2          1         2         3         8          4         9
   2        2          6         7         7         5          1          3         6         2         2          2         0
   3        4          2         2         2         3          4          1         8         2         9          4         2
```

I am trying to figure out how to sort the 'Date' index in ascending order by the month (Date is in DDMMYYYY). The end result will have both 'Import' and 'Export' columns for a single day (e.g 01012019 will have 4 and 2 and the dataframe will be sorted in ascending order by month).

I understand that in order to sort the date index, I need to use to_datetime to convert the type. This sort method works only if I drop my 'Units' index completely which I can't.

Is there a way? I have tried to play around with 'get_level_values' and giving a column name to my index with no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select levels by [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html), convert to `datetime`s and assign back:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df.columns.get_level_values(1), format='%d%m%Y')
df.columns = [df.columns.get_level_values(0), dates]
print (df)
       Units                           Import                        \
  2019-01-01 2019-02-01 2019-01-02 2019-02-02 2019-01-03 2019-02-03   
4          3          1          1          2          4          2   
2          2          3          2          4          2          1   
2          6          7          7          5          1          3   
4          2          2          2          3          4          1   

                 Export                                   
  2019-01-01 2019-02-01 2019-01-02 2019-02-02 2019-01-03  
4          2          1          1          2          2  
2          2          3          8          4          9  
2          6          2          2          2          0  
4          8          2          9          4          2
```

Then sorting like you need by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) - e.g. by second level:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
print (df)
      Import      Units     Export      Units     Export     Import  \
  2019-01-01 2019-01-01 2019-01-02 2019-01-02 2019-01-03 2019-01-03   
4          2          3          1          1          2          4   
2          2          2          8          2          9          2   
2          6          6          2          7          0          1   
4          8          2          9          2          2          4   

      Export      Units     Export     Import             
  2019-02-01 2019-02-01 2019-02-02 2019-02-02 2019-02-03  
4          1          1          2          2          2  
2          3          3          4          4          1  
2          2          7          2          5          3  
4          2          2          4          3          1
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Can you explain on the df.columns = [df.columns.get_level_values(0), dates]? Is this line used to combine back the index (0) and index (dates)? - Understood!